# Registration in Magento onepage checkout required field not displaying in form

Tags: magento

In my Magento 1.9 onepage checkout register page, showing after fillup all fields. location & mobile required, but in that such fields are not there, even in billing.phtml & shipping.pthml not there such fields.

Comment: Explain your question in more detail

Comment: I mean, when m adding some product to cart then clicking on proceed to checkout, then clicking on register, then it showing a registration form, when i fillup to click on continue, then it is showing with a dialog box --  location & mobile is required value. but such fields are not in there form.

Comment: check your form source. enable template path to find exact template check there.

Comment: Yeah i have already checked but unable to findout.

please help me to sort out this issue.

here is my url http://suratbasket.com/checkout/onepage/?register

Comment: I have checked your site. Please search for the "Location" is a required value. message in your installtion folder. so that you will get idea

Comment: i have already checked in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

Also checked in app\design\frontend\base\default\template\peristent\onepage\billing.phtml

but not found ther plzhelp me to findout exact file

Answer (score 0):

Please check this path `frontend\rwd\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml`. You will get your form fields in this page.

Comment: But my theme is ultimo, and login also not working.

so i think can i transfer only registration& login section from one theme to another, if yes then plz provide the necessary steps